# Swift tableview cell not showing background image on sections

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Inside cellForRowAtIndexPath method I am atribtuting to the cell a background image like so:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "other_car")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
cell.backgroundView = imageView
```

but the cell seems the same. How to correct this?

Comment: Did you try checking the frame of imageView? You might need to set it

Comment: Add your answer in the question as an answer instead.

Comment: did you resolved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an instance of UIImageView without setting its frame.

Set `imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)` for example to set its frame and make it visible.

Also you can set the frame directly while creating it like this:

`let imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200))`

Then you can set the image with:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "other_car")
```

or

`imageView.image = image // your UIImage instance`

Answer (score 0):

What I missed is this: before change the cell.backgroundView = imageView I inserted this peace of code, which cleared the color inside the cell:

`cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()`

Hope it helps other people